# Socket Exception during load test

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am testing our azure app developed in .net core simulating huge load. I am seeing many APi's getting socket error.

The destination APi is hosted in our network. Is there any limitation in azure where we can configure the limit of outbound socket connection.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

Comment: Some code would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Could be anything, but actual network **congestion/unreliability** is one definite possibility, as is that your own code is not properly managing connections, gracefully closing them when done, which artificially creates problems on the network.

Also please look at [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/322102/vsts-load-test-fails-socket-exception.html) thread for further information.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure App Service (assuming that's what we're talking about) has some hard connection limits.

From https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#cross-vm-numerical-limits:

> These limits apply only for customers of Basic or higher plans; in other words customers running on their own dedicated VMs. These limits are there to protect the entire VM even though one particular site may be with its limits described above. The limits are different depending on the size of VM configured.
>
> Connections across entire VM by SKU size:
> **Small (1920), Medium (3968), Large (8064)**

[This post explains it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/11/02/port-limit-for-an-azure-app-service/) in more detail.